# What is the difference between density of input layer and input_dim in Keras library?

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have a question about the terms of MLP in Keras.

what does the density of a layer mean?
is it the same as the number of neurons? if it is, so what's the role of input_dim?

Comment: Where did you read about "density of a layer"? It is not a term usually used in Keras

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Dense of a layer is something conventional when you define a layer for the network

Comment: No, it is not, I have not heard of this term before. "Density of a layer" is not a term that makes sense. I think you are confusing terms, this is why I asked where you read about those terms.

Answer (score 0):

I have never head of the "density" of a layer in the context of vanilla feed forward networks. I would assume it refers to the number of neurons, but really it depends on context.

Input layer with a certain dimension and the first hidden layer with input_dim argument are both equivalent ways to handle input in Keras.